# how to get data from Note 3 broken screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have a Samsung Note 3 and the phone went black due to me dropping it. I have since got a new phone but want to retrieve my photos from the old phone with the broken screen. The problem is that I have a passcode on my broken phone and I am unable to see or use the screen. I know the code but just don't know how to retrieve the photos. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Link the phone to a PC with cable and then it should load up the storage data if it is set automatically and then it should be under 'My Computer' as an external memory, your photos should be under DCIM.